How much torque is needed to drive a robot
I have a robot with four wheels, each of which have a motor in them. How much torque is required in each wheel to actually make it go forward? I don't have a real number for a coefficient of friction, efficiency %, definitive final velocity, time allotted for acceleration, or really any numbers confirmed for me, so I'm trying to do the whole thing with variables. I have attached an image below of the setup to hopefully convey the meaning of my words. Thanks in advance!


If you don't have real numbers, guess. Start at how big and heavy this robot is to be.

There needs to be a handbook to pull answers like this out of.  Because in the ideal circumstance, the answer is zero -- and when you get away from that ideal, every little detail matters.  Do I know the answer?  No.  There needs to be a reference that starts with how heavy the thing is, the surface it's traveling on, and how big the wheels are, then gives you a table of torques.

Let's call Torque, T.
$$T={F}*{r} \ \rightarrow F=\frac{T}{r}$$
Then the acceleration of the robot, $\alpha$ will be:
$$\alpha= \frac{F}{m}= \frac{F}{100}= \frac{T}{100r}$$
speed at time t,$\ v_t$:
$$v_t = \alpha*t$$
distance robot travels at time t, X:
$$X=1/2\  \alpha*t^2$$
So you can plug in the acceleration you need, $\ \alpha\ or \ the\ v_t$ and get the torque $T$.
The rolling friction is insignificant, but if you need to input it:
$$F_{effective}= F- mg*\mu$$
Edit
After Dave Tweed commented re the case of robot moving up or down on a ramp with inclination $\alpha$, In this case, we have to apply signs carefully regarding the slope. Also, this equation has 3 components: horizontal component, friction, and acceleration. We chose the acceleration we desire plus angle in radians:
$$F_{effective}= \frac{[mg*((sin \alpha)+\text{acceleration})]}{ cos\alpha }+  mg*\mu*cos \alpha$$

Another important element is the potential need to go up or down inclines.
